# Issue when trying to reinstall MOSS on a single server

Tags: installation, configuration-wizard, database, 2007

I am not an expert on the installation of SharePoint, but I have been trying to configure the MOSS installation on one of our DEV servers.

The first problem was found when trying to set up an SSP.  The SSP was created OK but there was an issue with finding the SQL Report Viewer assemblies which are required to view the SSP admin pages.

My environments team have kindly looked into this and decided to completely re-install MOSS on that box.

I have tried to re-run the config wizard to hook this server up to the existing config database and to re-create the central admin site.  However I now get a security exception when the config wizard is run.

These are the relevant lines from the config wizards log file:

- 05/05/2010 09:43:45  8  INF    Creating connection string for admin content db SharePoint_AdminContent_1c2efc32-a7c8-4e97-93d6-447c3ea5cd29 server XXXXXXXX\lob
- 05/05/2010 09:43:45  8  INF    Using NTLM for sql connection string
- 05/05/2010 09:43:45  8  INF    Openning configdb so that I can join it at server XXXXXXXX\lob database XXX_SharePoint_Config in farm mode
- 05/05/2010 09:43:45  8  INF    Now joining to farm at server XXXXXXXX\lob database XXX_SharePoint_Config
- 05/05/2010 09:43:47  8  ERR    Task configdb has failed with an unknown exception
- 05/05/2010 09:43:47  8  ERR    Exception: System.Security.SecurityException: Access denied.

The account that I am using as the central admin db access account has access to the config database (I have admin access so can check this) but I cannot ascertain if it has access to the existing admin content database.

Is this a known problem?  Am I following a red herring with the db access?  Is it worth blowing the whole configuration away and starting again?

Answer (score 1):

The required rights for the user accounts are public, dbcreator and securityadmin. No need to give him full dbowner rights.

This blog post explains the difference in Report Viewer webparts:
http://blogs.msdn.com/husainzgh/archive/2009/02/09/report-viewer-web-parts-for-sharepoint.aspx

Comment: Have you got any links to MS documentation on those database permissions I could do with sending that to my ENV team.

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721638.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution was because the config wizard had originally been run by another user.  I was trying to re-run it and my user account did not have appropriate access to the content database.

I had to re-run the config wizard using the account of the user who had run it the first time.  I suspect that any account with dbowner priviliges on the admin content database would have done the job though.

Still got the report viewer issue though.  I think that the SSP must need Report Viewer 2005 installed.